# Deserialization with Jackson ObjectMapper and Multiple Object Models

Tags: java, json, jackson

Can you use more than one class for Object De-Serialization? In my application I would like to de-serialize the below JSON file based one model class and then de-serialize a specific node with another model class which is more specific.

```
[ {
  "specie" : "HUMAN",
  "sourcebook" : "REVISED_CORE_RULEBOOK",
  "biography" : "C:\\Users\\troya\\IdeaProjects\\Hero Workshop\\com\\hw\\db\\species\\Human.md",
  "abilities" : [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  "size" : "MEDIUM",
  "speed" : 10,
  "fluentLanguages" : [ "BASIC" ],
  "literateLanguages" : [ "BASIC" ]
}, {
  "specie" : "BOTHAN",
  "sourcebook" : "REVISED_CORE_RULEBOOK",
  "biography" : "C:\\Users\\troya\\IdeaProjects\\Hero Workshop\\com\\hw\\db\\species\\Bothan.md",
  "abilities" : [ 0, 2, -2, 0, 0, 0 ],
  "size" : "MEDIUM",
  "speed" : 10,
  "fluentLanguages" : [ "BASIC", "BOTHESE" ],
  "literateLanguages" : [ "BASIC", "BOTHESE" ]
}, {
  "specie" : "CEREAN",
  "sourcebook" : "REVISED_CORE_RULEBOOK",
  "biography" : "C:\\Users\\troya\\IdeaProjects\\Hero Workshop\\com\\hw\\db\\species\\Cerean.md",
  "abilities" : [ 0, -2, 0, 2, 2, 0 ],
  "size" : "MEDIUM",
  "speed" : 10,
  "fluentLanguages" : [ "BASIC", "CEREAN" ],
  "literateLanguages" : [ "BASIC", "CEREAN" ]
}, {
  "specie" : "DUROS",
  "sourcebook" : "REVISED_CORE_RULEBOOK",
  "biography" : "C:\\Users\\troya\\IdeaProjects\\Hero Workshop\\com\\hw\\db\\species\\Duros.md",
  "abilities" : [ -2, 2, -2, 2, 0, 0 ],
  "size" : "MEDIUM",
  "speed" : 10,
  "fluentLanguages" : [ "BASIC", "DURESE" ],
  "literateLanguages" : [ "BASIC", "DURESE" ]
}, {
  "specie" : "EWOK",
  "sourcebook" : "REVISED_CORE_RULEBOOK",
  "biography" : "C:\\Users\\troya\\IdeaProjects\\Hero Workshop\\com\\hw\\db\\species\\Ewok.md",
  "abilities" : [ -2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  "size" : "SMALL",
  "speed" : 6,
  "fluentLanguages" : [ "EWOKESE" ],
  "literateLanguages" : [  ]
}, {
  "specie" : "GAMORREAN",
  "sourcebook" : "REVISED_CORE_RULEBOOK",
  "biography" : "C:\\Users\\troya\\IdeaProjects\\Hero Workshop\\com\\hw\\db\\species\\Gamorrean.md",
  "abilities" : [ 2, -2, 0, -2, 0, 0 ],
  "size" : "MEDIUM",
  "speed" : 10,
  "fluentLanguages" : [ "GAMORREAN" ],
  "literateLanguages" : [  ]
}, {
  "specie" : "GUNGAN",
  "sourcebook" : "REVISED_CORE_RULEBOOK",
  "biography" : "C:\\Users\\troya\\IdeaProjects\\Hero Workshop\\com\\hw\\db\\species\\Gungan.md",
  "abilities" : [ 0, 0, 2, -2, 0, 0 ],
  "size" : "MEDIUM",
  "speed" : 10,
  "fluentLanguages" : [ "BASIC", "GUNGAN" ],
  "literateLanguages" : [ "BASIC", "GUNGAN" ]
} ]
```

I would like to first deserialize it utilizing one model class:

```
package com.hw.db.sw;

import com.hw.db.sw.species.Specie;

public class Species {
    private Specie specie;
    private Sourcebook sourcebook;

    public Species() {
    }
    public Species(Specie specie, Sourcebook sourcebook) {
        this.specie = specie;
        this.sourcebook = sourcebook;
    }
    public Specie getSpecie() {
        return specie;
    }
    public void setSpecie(Specie specie) {
        this.specie = specie;
    }
    public Sourcebook getSourcebook() {
        return sourcebook;
    }
    public void setSourcebook(Sourcebook sourcebook) {
        this.sourcebook = sourcebook;
    }
}
```

And then deserialize a specific node in the JSON array with another model class:

```
package com.hw.db.sw.species;

import com.hw.db.sw.Sourcebook;
import com.hw.db.sw.Species;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class Human extends Species {
    private File biography;
    private List<Integer> abilities;
    private Size size;
    private int speed;
    private List<Language> fluentLanguages;
    private List<Language> literateLanguages;

    public Human(Specie specie, Sourcebook sourcebook, File biography, List<Integer> abilities, Size size, int speed, List<Language> fluentLanguages, List<Language> literateLanguages) {
        super(specie, sourcebook);
        this.biography = biography;
        this.abilities = abilities;
        this.size = size;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.fluentLanguages = fluentLanguages;
        this.literateLanguages = literateLanguages;
    }
    public File getBiography() {
        return biography;
    }
    public void setBiography(File biography) {
        this.biography = biography;
    }
    public List<Integer> getAbilities() {
        return abilities;
    }
    public void setAbilities(List<Integer> abilities) {
        this.abilities = abilities;
    }
    public Size getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void setSize(Size size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }
    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
    public List<Language> getFluentLanguages() {
        return fluentLanguages;
    }
    public void setFluentLanguages(List<Language> fluentLanguages) {
        this.fluentLanguages = fluentLanguages;
    }
    public List<Language> getLiterateLanguages() {
        return literateLanguages;
    }
    public void setLiterateLanguages(List<Language> literateLanguages) {
        this.literateLanguages = literateLanguages;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you serializing with class `Human` and need to deserialize with `Human` and `Species`?

Comment: you can use inherited class for serialization& deserialization. If you prefer to ignore certain field  `@JsonIgnore`  annotation on field will help you, if you need to ignore couple of fields from a class annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties({})` is your helper.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance#bd-ignoring-properties-from-a-supertype .This article may help you.

Comment: @Steephen I was trying to De-Serialize by Species and then based on specified selection ie: Human, Bothan, Cerean… The Human class is the specific model for each object and the Species class is more general. Or would it be better to create an interface for each species and implement that interface in the species class?